# Unreachable Code Detected Return Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to return value with this issue?
Help me please.

```
protected string SendState(Object ID_DIP,Object ID_SEQ,Object MODUL)
{
    try
    {
        ViewState["ssDIP"] = ID_DIP.ToString();
        ViewState["ssSEQ"] = ID_SEQ.ToString();
        ViewState["ssMOD"] = MODUL.ToString();

        return ID_DIP.AsString();
        return ID_SEQ.AsString();
        return MODUL.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but if you change the return type from `string` to `IEnumerable<string>`, then you can change `return` into `yield return`, and you will have an iterator block that returns many strings, one after the other, when the consumer `foreach`es through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first thing is u have multiple return values, so ur code wouldn't work, so u can use `List<String>` & to return in catch case, u could use a var at the top of method definition, like this--->

```
public List<string> SendState(Object ID_DIP,Object ID_SEQ,Object MODUL)
{
     var returnValue = new List<string>();
          try
          {
                ViewState["ssDIP"] = ID_DIP.ToString();
                ViewState["ssSEQ"] = ID_SEQ.ToString();
                ViewState["ssMOD"] = MODUL.ToString();


                returnValue.add(ID_DIP.AsString());
                returnValue.add(ID_DIP.AsString());
                returnValue.add(MODUL.ToString());

          }
          catch (Exception)
          {
                returnValue = null;
          }
     return returnValue;
}
```

now u can use the above method like this--->

```
var result = SendState( params )  //<--- params r ur parameters
if(result != null)
    // proceed
else
    // no value found
```

Comment: `protected List<string> SendState` ?

Answer (score 8):

You have **multiple return statements**, your code will not execute statements after first return statement. You **can't return multiple values** from your method, if you want to return multiple values you can either return `List<string>` for your case or create a temporary class and return its object.

*In your code you are using `AsString`, I think you probably meant `ToString`*

Define a class like:

```
public class MyReturnObject
{
    public string ID_DIP { get; set; }
    public string ID_SEQ { get; set; }
    public string MODUL { get; set; }
}
```

Modify your method like:

```
protected MyReturnObject SendState(Object ID_DIP, Object ID_SEQ, Object MODUL)
{
    try
    {
        ViewState["ssDIP"] = ID_DIP.ToString();
        ViewState["ssSEQ"] = ID_SEQ.ToString();
        ViewState["ssMOD"] = MODUL.ToString();

        MyReturnObject obj = new MyReturnObject();
        obj.ID_DIP = ID_DIP.ToString();
        obj.ID_SEQ = ID_SEQ.ToString();
        obj.MODUL = MODUL.ToString();
        return obj;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want return multiple results which has the same type. I suggest you should apply coroutine pattern. Specifics at here as code below:

```
protected IEnumerable<string> SendState(Object ID_DIP,Object ID_SEQ,Object MODUL)
{   
   ViewState["ssDIP"] = ID_DIP.AsString();
   ViewState["ssSEQ"] = ID_SEQ.AsString();
   ViewState["ssMOD"] = MODUL.ToString();

   yield return ID_DIP.AsString();
   yield return ID_SEQ.AsString();
   yield return MODUL.ToString();    
}
```

You take reference the [link](http://blog.asymptotic.co.uk/2009/11/coroutines-in-csharp/) to get more understand about coroutine pattern in C#.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, methods generally return only **one** value. This value can be an object with multiple fields.

If you need to return multiple values from a method, you can use [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) parameters or return a type instance containing all the values.

As Habib *[suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16537691/447156)*, returning `List<string>` is a good approach in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can only return a single value from a method, so of your three `return` statements only the first one will execute.

If you want to return multiple strings, return an array of strings:

```
protected string[] SendState(Object ID_DIP,Object ID_SEQ,Object MODUL) {
  try {
    ViewState["ssDIP"] = ID_DIP.ToString();
    ViewState["ssSEQ"] = ID_SEQ.ToString();
    ViewState["ssMOD"] = MODUL.ToString();

    return new string[] {
      ID_DIP.ToString(),
      ID_SEQ.ToString(),
      MODUL.ToString()
    };

  } catch (Exception) {
    return null; // or perhaps an empty array...?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any code that is written after the first return statement (within the same block) will not execute. In case you want to return multiple values from a method, consider using objects.